# Correlation coefficient in r drc package

Tags: r, plot, statistics, correlation

i want to find the correlation of the adjuste of the curve plotted and the data, anyone knows how to do that?

```
library(drc)

S.alba.m1 <- drm(DryMatter~Dose, Herbicide, data = S.alba, fct = LL.4())
plot(S.alba.m1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fitted`:

```
cor(S.alba$DryMatter, fitted(S.alba.m1))
```

Also check out the `modelFit` function: `?modelFit` for various tests.